# swapping Kth node from beginning and Kth node from end in a linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

If I get the linked list input as: 1->2->3->4 and K=1,num=2

The desired output for the given question is 4->3->2->1

Swapping of data is not allowed and I am given head pointer, the value of K, and num as arguments of the function.

I am getting segmentation fault despite checking all corner cases already num>K,K==1,K==num,K<=num/2. Here num represents the no. of nodes in a linked list, K is an integer type variable denoting the position of the node to be swapped.

MY APPROACH: I have first traversed the whole linked list to get previous node and current node pointers to both the Kth node from the end and Kth node from the beginning as prevnode1,currnode1,prevnode2, and currnode2. Then I have changed the next pointers of both current nodes with the help of an arbitrary temp pointer. Then I have applied various cases for changing the next pointers of previous nodes.

Please have a look on my code

```
Node *swapkthnode(Node* head, int num, int K)
{
    int flag=0;
    Node *prevnode1=head,*currnode1,*currnode2,*temp=NULL,*prevnode2=NULL;
    if(K>num)
        return head;
    if(num==(2*K-1))
        return head;
    currnode1=head;
    int i=1;
    while(currnode1!=NULL&&i<K)
    {
        prevnode1=currnode1;
        currnode1=currnode1->next;
        i++;
    }
    i=1;
    currnode2=head;
    while(currnode2!=NULL&&i<num-K)
    {
        prevnode2=currnode2;
        currnode2=currnode2->next;
        i++;
    }
    if(currnode1&&currnode1->next==currnode2)
        flag=1;
    if(currnode1&&currnode2)
    {
        temp=currnode1->next;
        currnode1->next=currnode2->next;
        currnode2->next=temp;
    }    
    if(prevnode1==NULL)
    {
        head=currnode2;
        prevnode2->next=currnode1;
    }
    if(prevnode2==NULL)
    {
        head=currnode1;
        prevnode1->next=currnode2;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        currnode1->next->next=currnode2;

    }
    if(prevnode1!=NULL&&prevnode2!=NULL)
    {

        prevnode2->next=currnode1;
        prevnode1->next=currnode2;
    }
    return head;
    // Your Code here
}
```